# Windows RPC access denied even with RPC_C_AUTHN_NONE

Tags: c, windows, rpc

I have this error while trying to connect my RPC client to my RPC server:

```
Error occurred:5
```

Some googling showed me the meaning of this error: `access denied`.
The trouble does not come from the firewall.

Here is the server part, where I specify RPC_C_AUTHN_NONE to let everyone connect:

```
RPC_STATUS status;
printf("RPC Server Starting...\n");

status = RpcServerUseProtseqEp(
    (unsigned char *)"ncacn_ip_tcp",
    RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,
    (unsigned char *)"9191",
    RPC_C_AUTHN_NONE);
if (status) { printf("Error:%d\n", status); exit(status); }
printf("RPC Server Configured\n");
```

Here is the client part raising the error:

```
RpcTryExcept {
    unsigned char szMsg[] = "Client: I can RPC now!\n";
    md5(szMsg);
} RpcExcept(1) {
    printf("Error occurred:%d\n", RpcExceptionCode());
}
RpcEndExcept
```

How do I correct this issue, in order to let any RPC client connects?

And in the same order, do you know a good RPC documentation for Windows RPC authentication?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent some time figuring why this happened, and I provide this answer as I found a solution, in order to help those who might encounter this trouble:

By default, RPC connection are only granted to authenticated clients. This can be changed by editing a registry entry or applying a GPO to disable restrictions for unauthenticated users as specified [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb895085).